# Does anyone have a catkinized version of the hector_navigation package?

Tags: ros, hector-navigation, hector

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I was trying to catkinize the hector_navigation package myself but it is quite time consuming. If anyone has even catkinized a couple of packages, particularly the hector_exploration_planner, please do post the link here, it would help immensely.

Thank You.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/188565/does-anyone-have-a-catkinized-version-of-the-hector_navigation-package?/) by [Ashwin27](https://answers.ros.org/users/19896/ashwin27/) on ROS Answers with karma: 34 on 2014-08-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There´s [this pull request](https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/hector_navigation/pull/2) that we have not tried yet (but should) and [this fork](https://github.com/UNR-RoboticsResearchLab/hector_navigation/tree/catkin_devel) that both provide catkinized versions. If you try them, let me know if things worked :)

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2014-08-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ashwin27](https://answers.ros.org/users/19896/ashwin27/) on 2014-08-04**:
Thanks for the answer, Stefan!
I managed to get the forked link to work after solving a few compilation errors, it appears to be running perfectly now!